# How to print page source with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have the below code, which searches Twitter and scrolls through the infinite scrolling. The line 'print data' is not working for me though. Any ideas?

```
# Import Selenium stuff
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

# Import other needed packages
import sys
import unittest, time, re

# Call up Firefox, do the Twitter search, click the "All" link and start paging
class Sel(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "https://twitter.com"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True
def test_sel(self):
    driver = self.driver
    delay = 3
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/search?q=storstrut&src=typd")
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("All").click()
    for i in range(1,100):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(4)
    html_source = driver.page_source
    data = html_source.encode('utf-8')
    print data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: You should wait 400 seconds.. you're looping and sleeping on each iteration.

Comment: Sorry, but could you tell me how that is done (in code)?

Answer (score 17):

you have a lot of unused code and weird imports, but you are on the right track.

Here is a simplified version, with comments explaining.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


# launch Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# load Twitter page
driver.get("https://twitter.com/search?q=storstrut&src=typd")

# the following javascript scrolls down the entire page body.  Since Twitter
# uses "inifinite scrolling", more content will be added to the bottom of the
# DOM as you scroll... since it is in the loop, it will scroll down up to 100 
# times.
for _ in range(100):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

# print all of the page source that was loaded
print driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")

# quit and close browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, but somehow the first messier code actually scrolls down, while his cleaner one does not...

Comment: @textnet I can confirm that this answer works, are you using the latest version of Selenium?